# Hibernate Session is invalidated after ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way to continue using an thread bound hibernate session after constraintviolation exception has been thrown? I'm giving a short example here:

```
    Parent other=service.load(33); // loads a new parent
    try {
        Parent p=new Parent();
        p.setName("A name");
        service.save(p); // a @Transactional spring service class, throws ConstraintViolationException - name should be at least 15 characters long
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e){
        // i would like to handle validation errors and proceed normally
        // but the session is allready closed here
    }
    System.out.println("Children: " + other.getChildren()); // lazy initialization exception, even when using opensessioninview
```

From now on the hibernate session is completely useless, even for read-only operations like rendering a lazy collection in view using OpenSessionInView pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)'s documentation states that *If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.*.

AFAIK, there's no way to recover from this, I recall someone at work warning me not to use the session-per-request/OpenSessionInView-pattern because of these kinds of problems.

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but how unsatisfying!  In an application using JPA (Hibernate 3) and Spring, I noticed that a `ConstraintViolationException` exception was thrown when we explicitly flushed the entity manager after a merge but if we removed the flush, a more generic Spring `TransactionSystemException` was thrown containing a nested `RollbackException` which, in turn, contained the root `ConstraintViolationException`.  After catching the `TransactionSystemException`, however, the entity manager (hibernate session) is still usable.  No more lazy initialization errors!

Comment: @Brice: considering that the documentation explicitly says not to use the Session after an exception is thrown, finding a workaround to still use it doesn't make it any less dangerous. It might work for some cases and not for others, leading to indeterminate behavior. However, if it works for you without any problems, good! Still, personally, I'd prefer not to use any such "gimmicks" and instead work out what's wrong with the transaction in the first place (like in this question for example, validate the input some other way rather than leave validation for the database).

Comment: I agree. To be more clear, the issue has to do with bean validation (JSR 303) exceptions (`javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` not database constraint exceptions) causing the session/entity manager to throw an exception rendering itself useless. It would be nice to be able to still use the session for read only queries after pre-persist/pre-update/pre-remove validation fails. In this case, there is nothing happening on the database level that would make using the session dangerous (as far as I can tell), it's simply business rules rendering a certain entity invalid.

Comment: A better alternative, perhaps, than my gimmicky solution above would be to re-create the session if it becomes invalid but I'm not sure how to do this when using the OpenSessionInView (OpenEntityManagerInView with JPA) pattern (e.g. using the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter provided by Spring).

Comment: @Brice: when using Spring, the Transactional-annotation has a field called noRollbackFor (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor%28%29), which can be used to list exception classes which should not cause a rollback in cases where you know to expect them (like for example, when creating a new user, the existence of the user is checked first with a query that should return a single result using getSingleResult, but ends up throwing NoResultException, the transaction is still needed to add the new user).

Answer (score 5):

Use a StatelessSession instead of a Session. That is the trick.

With a StatelessSession you can continue after any exceptions as it is possible in SQL (even inside one transaction - no commit/rollback is done by hibernate). That is ideal for bulk updates/inserts or for checking if unique constraints are violated.

But beware, a StatelessSession has many Restrictions compared with a normal session. Please refer to the Hibernate documentaion / Javadocs for that.

Comment: Works fine for me! ( so far )

Comment: Thank you. worked. I just needed inserts and it worked.