# Hibernate session object after exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have list of records of type **class A** ,let's say `List<A> list=new ArrayList<A>();`.

Now i am trying to a save every record of A into database by using `session.save();`.
    If my second records fails then rest of my records are failed. In that case i try to remove that second record from the session by using `session.evict(obj)`. But still I am getting the same behaviour.
    Below is the code :

```
 for(A a:list){
    try{
    session.save(a);
    }
    catch{
    log.exception("Primary key");
    session.evict(a);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can't continue to use a session after an exception has occured. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109175/hibernate-session-is-invalidated-after-constraintviolationexception

Comment: I think you'll have to rework your logic, because after an exception has been thrown in Hibernate, the behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: After exception also i can still use the session object.

Answer (score 0):

call `saveOrUpdate(a)` instead of `session.save(a);`

**edit**

```
start transaction
    session.saveOrUpdate(a);
    a.getId() // this should have id.
    return a;   
end transaction
```

Comment: I want to return the generated identifier .

Comment: By Using saveOrUpdate i can't find my generated identifier
I need to return the identifier

Comment: You can return the same object that should have the generated identifier.

Comment: saveOrUpdate doesnot return anything ryt? Please suggest if i am wrong

Comment: Still facing the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

As per your code I have not seen `session.flush(); session.clear();` this methods in your code.  so update your code as follows

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
int i = 0;
for(A a:list){
    try{
        session.save(a);
        if (i % 20 == 0 ) { 
            //20, same as the JDBC batch size
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
        i++;        
    } catch {
        log.exception("Primary key");
        session.evict(a);
    }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

why are you evicting it from session? 
You can ignore it.
it will then save the successful object while iteration and leave the error one's.
Other way is you can flush the session once object is evicted in catch block.
Hope this may work