# Spring transactional & JPA: handle exception when saving multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactional

Articles are scraped from the web, so all properties (like `Medium`, `Source` etc) initially have an id of NULL and the scraped data in their fields. Before saving an article, the *toEntities()-methods make sure that the data that already exists in the DB, is reused. If the data is new, it's created via cascading in `Article`.

It is possible that a duplicate article is scraped which throws a "not unique exception" on save, which is good, but after that the other articles should still be saved. I guess I'm struggling with handling this exception correctly. A workaround would be to check if the entity exists but this would result in unnecessary work for 95% of the time.

In the code you see my final attempt, where I tried to save each article in its own transaction but I get these exceptions:

- [SqlExceptionHelper.java:129] Duplicate entry '5628BA1A0D4115E091B5EED94FEF5840' for key 'UK_ftcejiicdrly4nl40b7lbvx6e' (the duplicate is determined by the hash value).
- org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in
  org.observer.media.model.Article entry (don't flush the Session after
  an exception occurs)

Here is the code of `ArticleService`. If you spot other things that are wrong with this class I'd be glad to hear them too.

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SourcesRepository sourcesRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MediumRepository mediumRepository;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("o.o.m.s.ArticleService");

    @Transactional
    public void save(Iterable<Article> articles) {
        for (Article article : articles) {
            save(article);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(Article article) {
        dataToEntities(article);
        try {
            articleRepository.save(article);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Iterable<Article> articles) {
        if (articles == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Article article : articles) {
            if (article.getId() != 0L) {
                delete(article);
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Article article) {
        article.setMedium(null);
        article.setCategories(null);
        article.setSources(null);
        articleRepository.delete(article);
    }

    private void dataToEntities(Article article) {
        categoriesToEntities(article);
        sourcesToEntities(article);
        mediumToEntity(article);
    }

    private void mediumToEntity(Article article) {
        if (article.getMedium() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Medium medium = mediumRepository.findByName(article.getMedium().getName());
        if (medium != null) {
            article.setMedium(medium);
        }
    }

    private void sourcesToEntities(Article article) {
        Set<Source> sources = new HashSet<>();

        if (article.getSources() == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Source source : article.getSources()) {
            Source entity = sourcesRepository.findByName(source.getName());
            if (entity != null) {
                sources.add(entity);
            } else {
                sources.add(source);
            }
        }

        article.setSources(sources);
    }

    private void categoriesToEntities(Article article) {
        Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

        if (article.getCategories() == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Category category : article.getCategories()) {
            category = categoryRepository.findByName(category.getName());
            categories.add(category);
        }

        article.setCategories(categories);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I followed up on the possible duplicate question and tried

1. the NoRollBackFor-option with all possible exceptions like below on both methods:

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = {ConstraintViolationException.class, MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class, DataIntegrityViolationException.class, AssertionFailure.class, RollbackException.class})

This resulted in "TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly".

2. I discarded the StatelessSession approach because it deviates away from the JPA spec, and because cascading would not work according to the docs. Also, it exposes a variant of Session which feels even more like a hack than just exposing the normal hibernate Session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Session is invalidated after ConstraintViolationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109175/hibernate-session-is-invalidated-after-constraintviolationexception)

Comment: Ty @Taylor, I followed up on your link but the proposed solutions didn't work out for me as you can read in my edit.